# Spring Eureka is refusing connections from service which tries to discover Spring Config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka

I am trying to learn Spring Cloud and have started by creating a kind of a "hello world" which consists of:

- `time-service`: A Spring Boot simple app that returns the current time.
- `time-eureka-server`: A Spring Boot Eureka server.
- `time-config-server`: A Spring Boot Config server.

`time-service` is configured to use `time-eureka-server` to discover `time-config-server` and fetch the configuration from there (just a simple configuration parameter with the format of the time to be returned). Here is the content of `time-service`'s `bootstrap.properties`:

```
spring.application.name=time-service

# We tell the service how to find the configuration server
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId=time-config-server

# We tell the service to retry to fetch the configuration in case the config server is not available
# This is useful when all the services are started up at the same time, and the config server is not up yet by the
# time this services wants to fetch its configuration
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
spring.cloud.config.retry.max-attempts=50
spring.cloud.config.retry.initial-interval=1500
spring.cloud.config.retry.multiplier=1.5

# This value will be overridden with the URL in docker-compose.yml when we use different containers for
# the Eureka server and the time service ('localhost' will not work in that case).
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

At this point, is worth mentioning that this works well if I start up the three applications one by one, either using my IDE or Docker containers. I mean, URI's are accessible and everything works just fine. It actually works regardless of the order I start the services/containers, that is, I can start up `time-service` first and this will wait for the others to be up and running (notice retry configuration above). I mention this because I have found many people asking a similar question to mine, which answer was to set the retry configuration. I don't think this is my case, although I might be wrong.

Now, my problems start when I use Docker compose to start up the three containers **at the same time**. When I do that, `time-services` fails with this error:

```
time-service_1        | 2020-06-10 11:05:20.071  WARN 1 --- [           main] lientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration : Could not locate configserver via discovery
time-service_1        |
time-service_1        | org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://time-eureka-server:8761/eureka/apps/": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

...

time-service_1        |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
time-service_1        |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
time-service_1        | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
time-service_1        |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
time-service_1        |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
time-service_1        |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
time-service_1        |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)
time-service_1        |
time-service_1        | 2020-06-10 11:05:20.462  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
```

`time-eureka-service` refuses the connection, which makes `time-service` use what I think must be the default location of a Spring Config server (`http://localhost:8888`) instead of the right one (I am using a different port).

My *guess* is that `time-service` hits `time-eureka-service` just when this is in the process of starting up, at a point where it can respond to requests (refusing the connection) but can't provide any "friendly" response (like "I cannot find what you are looking for because it is not registered yet"). A friendly response, or a no response at all will make `time-service` wait and retry, as configured, but with this "connection refused", `time-service` seems to give up immediately with no re-attempts at all.

Since the error happens only few seconds after I start the `time-service` container, I am pretty sure that it is not retrying, it's failing straight away after the first "connection refused" from `time-eureka-server`.

So, my question is: is it possible to ask `time-service` to retry when it gets this "connection refused" error? Is there any other way to solve my problem?

You can find the source code of all three services here: https://github.com/Time-app-with-Spring-Cloud

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: When I encountered this issue I made use of [wait-for-it script](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to check if a particular host port combination is reachable before starting the dependent container. This is also inline with what the official [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) suggest.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that, and other simpler similar solution (a hacky `sleep 5` before starting up `time-service`) and this certainly works. I have also tried to mess with `docker-compose.xml` to make `time-service` starts first (by making the others depend on it) and this also works -- `time-service` will start, see that `time-eureka-server` is not available and wait for it and `time-config-server` to start up without failing.

However, I still have the feeling that this problem shouldn't be solved via Docker. I think the problem is in `time-service` which is unable to handle the scenario.